# How can I include the PDB files into a Package ZIP file using Visual Studio 2012 and MSdeploy

Tags: webdeploy, pdb-files

I need to be able to include the PDB files into the ZIP file that gets created when I run the "Publish" command in Visual Studio to create the MSDeploy package.

I can see the PDB files in the folder but they don't make it into the ZIP file

Is there some configuration setting that I need to set?

Yes I am aware this is not standard practice!

Comment: Did the answer solve your issue? If so can you mark this question as answered?

Comment: Sorry I forgot about this one. The answer didn't solve the issue, see below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by doing this in the project file for the web project

```
<ItemGroup>
  <_CustomFilesPdb Include="$(OutDir)\SEEK.*.pdb" Exclude="$(OutDir)\*Tests*.pdb" />
  <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFilesPdb.Identity)">
    <DestinationRelativePath>bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
  </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have two options.

#### Easy solution

On the publish dialog on the Settings tab you can set the configuration to Debug and publish using that.

#### Slightly more involved solution

If you want to build in Release mode but still include PDBs then you can edit the publish profile. When you create a publish profile on the VS publish dialog we create an a file for that under Properties\PublishProfile (My Project\PublishProfiles for VB). You can add specific MSBuild elements to customize these. In your case the behavior is controlled by a property named ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol which is set to `true` if you are building in Release. So just declare the property to be false in your .pubxml file by adding  the element below directly above the closing `</Project>` tag.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>false</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You can continue to publish from the publish dialog, it will preserve your edits.

Comment: There is also project-level setting, if you don't use publish profiles. http://i.stack.imgur.com/OjBNb.png